# How to find a row in a table based on a numerical range?

Tags: formulas, libreoffice-calc

I have a table of chapters from the book A Game of Thrones, and the page that this chapter starts. I want to take a given page number, find the nearest numerical value going down, and then pick out the chapter name for that row. For example:

```
Eddard II   -  104
Tyrion II   -  113
Catelyn III -  122
```

Given the input `119`, I want to find the next lowest number on the right-hand column, which is `113`, and then output the chapter name on the left-hand column, so `Tyrion II`. I can't work out how to do this formulaically: it looks like it should be a job for VLOOKUP, but I don't know if VLOOKUP can accommodate ranges, less than or greater than when looking for a row. How should I go about this?

Excel-based solutions are also fine, so long as they're applicable to Libreoffice Calc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the chapter names are in column A and the page numbers are in column B and the given input is in C1, then

```
=INDEX(A1:A10,MATCH(C1,B1:B10,1))
```

VLOOKUP can also search the nearest value in sorted columns - see help VLOOKUP and there the parameter "sort order". But it cannot look to the left, so you have to use INDEX MATCH in this case.

Greetings

Axel

Comment: That's great, works perfectly. Would you be willing to explain why it works? I'm not familiar with MATCH.

Comment: There is a help page for each spreadsheet function in libreoffice. Please use it. https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Spreadsheet_Functions#MATCH